# Is it possible to disable click > highlight > "accidentals" character swap in Windows?

Tags: windows, mouse, cursor, selection

I have been wanting to ask this for so long and it just finally got to me.

Have you ever been coding or typing and needed to click on a portion of text to highlight it and as you begin to do so, for whatever reason, somehow, one or more characters switch places?

I don't know how else to describe this if there's a better way but I would sure like to disabled it.

On highlight anything, make no assumptions of what my mouse can do with text. It highlights and it clicks. It shall never have lazy-copy-and-paste-with-somehow-just-a-mouse-click features.

Please kindly tell me this is a setting that can be turned off. Accessibility maybe?